# Problema com algoritmo em C

Tags: c, algoritmo, recursão

Boas pessoal , é o seguinte , eu ando a desenvolver um projeto que pretende encontrar uma palavra numa sopa de letras , as regras são as seguintes:

> A letra pode ser encontrada em qualquer posição
>  *( Este, Norte , Sul , Oeste, Nordeste , Nordoeste , Suldeste , Suldoeste )*
>   A palavra pode ser encontrada de trás para a frente 
> *( por exemplo: 'ANA' pode ser encontrada em 'AN' )*

Bem , acontece que o meu algoritmo recursivo não funciona , gostava de saber se alguém tem alguma explicação para isso !!
Obrigado!

Código:

```
void caminhos(char **sopa) {
    char *palavra = "PORTO";

    char sopa2[][5]= {'P','O','Y','T','O',
                      'X','R','T','O','Y',
                      'Y','Z','C','A','S',
                      'X','Z','Y','X','A'};
    // ciclos a ser implementados

    int *referencias = procurarPalavra("PORTO", sopa2);


    imprimirReferencias(referencias,(int)strlen(palavra));


}



int *procurarPalavra(char *palavra, char sopa[][5]) {
    //esta funcao cria espaço para as referencias, chama a funcao recursiva, e retorna as referencias

    //  array de ints com as referencias dos caminhos e com tamanho de palavra
    int *referencias = (int*)calloc(strlen(palavra),sizeof(int));

    // procura na posicao (0,0) pela palavra PORTO
    procurarLetras(0,0,sopa,palavra,0,referencias);

    return referencias;

}

void procurarLetras(int row,int col, char m[][5],char *palavra,int coordenada,int *referencias) {


    // consistencia
    if( (row < 0 || col < 0) && row>4 && col>5) return;

    // (palavra) seja '\0'
    if(*palavra == '\0') {
        puts("\n Encontrei palavra na sopa :)");
        imprimirReferencias(referencias, 5);
        exit(1);
    }
    // se char for igual à palavra
    if(m[row][col] == *palavra) {
        *(referencias+1) = coordenada;
        printf("\n LETRA: %c | COORDENADA: %d",*palavra,coordenada);
        procurarLetras(row, col, m, palavra+1, coordenada, referencias);
        return;
    }




    // 1 ESTE
    procurarLetras(row, col+1, m, palavra, 1, referencias);

    // 2 SUL
    procurarLetras(row+1, col, m, palavra, 2, referencias);

    // 3 NORTE
    procurarLetras(row-1, col, m, palavra, 3, referencias);

    // 4 OESTE
    procurarLetras(row, col-1, m, palavra, 4, referencias);

    // 5 NORDESTE
    procurarLetras(row-1, col+1, m, palavra, 5, referencias);

    // 6 NORDOESTE
    procurarLetras(row-1, col-1, m, palavra, 6, referencias);

    // 7 SULDESTE
    procurarLetras(row+1, col+1, m, palavra, 7, referencias);

    // 8 SULDOESTE
    procurarLetras(row+1, col-1, m, palavra, 8, referencias);
}




void imprimirReferencias(int *referencias, int tamanho) {
    // imprime as referencias da palavra na sopa
    for(int i=0;i<tamanho;i++) {
        printf("--> %d",*(referencias+i));
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Você tem certeza de que este teste: if( (row < 0 || col < 0) && row>4 && col>5) return;
 está correto? Não deveria ser OU (||)? Da forma que está row > 4 e col <= 5, por exemplo, será considerado válido.

Comment: Sim , esse eu já tinha mudado para || esquecime de mudar aqui , no entanto não funciona à mesma , obrigado !

Comment: Porquê a solução recursiva ? Certamente não é a mais natural

Comment: é a que contém menos linhas de código ,e também me desafia mais ..

Comment: Tens alguma ideia de como seria iterativamente?

Comment: Sim, iterativamente é mais simples mas mais extenso. Quanto ao código à várias coisas que não são muito claras e que dificultam dar uma resposta sem saber o real objetivo. 1) Como é chamada a função `caminhos` e qual o parametro passado ? 2) O inicializador da `sopa2` dois está incorreto e faltam várias chaves nele. 3) O que significa o array retornado das referencias ? Normalmente uma local numa matriz tem duas coordenadas mas não me parece o caso do seu código. 4) A ordem das funções não está correta a menos que esteja a usar prototipos/declarações 5)O tamanho no `calloc` está incorreto.